# Create a link with an anchor with Twig path function in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to create a link with an anchor like "www.example.com/services#anchor1" in my Twig template. So far I've been using the **path** function to create links `path('services')`. I have tried with `path('services#anchor1')` but obviously it doesn't work.

It doesn't seem to be a lot of information about this function or it's just that I can't find it. Any idea about how could I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try `<a href="{{ path('_welcome') }}#home">Home</a>`

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed and so simple! :)

Comment: Do you know how to do this if the URL is generated with the symfony router service ?

Comment: funktastic. was thinking about it and didn't fall on this simple solution.+1

Comment: @Elorfin That's why the fragment option was introduced in 3.2. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 43):

As of Symfony 3.2 you can use the `_fragment` option:

```
<a href="{{ path('homepage', {'_fragment': 'home'}) }}">Home</a>
```

Check out the [feature introduction](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-routing-improvements#added-support-for-url-fragments) on the Symfony blog.

Comment: This one is correct way for Symfony 3.2+. Thanks to @COil.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I had just link being generated in the a tag but then needed to open in a new page aka add `target="_blank"` to the generated url so I changed the href to this and it worked!

```
<a class="new-item"  target="_blank" href="{{ link(item.title, item.url) }}"></a>
```