# Is it possible to make an anchor to an external page, with an id referencing a specific html section in this page (symfony)

Tags: html, symfony, anchor

I have a banner at the top of my main page, and this banner gets a link to another page on the website.

exemple:

`<a href="https://www.myWebSite.com/other-page-than-home">click here</a>`

This far, everything is working well

This link is defined in the database and may also relate another website (that's why I don't use the traditional twig: "{{ path('road') }}" here).

My problem is when I want to reference a specific section of the page:

`<a href="https://www.myWebSite.com/other-page-than-home#section-1">click here</a>`

On click on the anchor, nothing happens, instead of requesting the new URI into my browser to load the new page.

If I directly request this URI with my browser, it loads my page correctly at the good section

So I don't know if it's possible to link to a specific section of another page with this method, and if it's possible, why does it don't work? Is it a Symfony problem? twig problem? server-side problem?

Comment: I just tried  `<a href="{{ path('_welcome') }}#home">Home</a>` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794886/create-a-link-with-an-anchor-with-twig-path-function-in-symfony-2/8794949)

also tried: `<a href="{{ banner.urlLink }}#home">Home</a>` and both `{{ relative_path() }}` and `{{ absolute_url() }}` twig methods.

Nothing worked

Comment: Hi Thibault, what is the actual link that is generated on the page? (see F12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for trying to help! So the link was generated successfully on the page, but i've just figured out that a litlle innocent piece of code, set in the main layer by an other developer was making my trouble:

```
$("#whatBonClick a").on('click', function(event) {
            if (this.hash !== "") {
                event.preventDefault();
                var hash = this.hash;
                ...
            }
```

So I just had my self little piece of code to fix this problem:

```
$("#whatBonClick a").on('click', function(event) {
            let requestedHref = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href').split('#')[0]
            let baseHref = window.location.href.split('#')[0]
            if ((requestedHref.length === 0 || baseHref === requestedHref) && this.hash !== "") {
                event.preventDefault();
                var hash = this.hash;
                ...
            }
```

And now everything is working perfectly!

ps: `(requestedHref.length === 0 || baseHref === requestedHref)` is here to also trigger an anchor like `<a href="#SectionId">*</a>`